# Does this use of the semicolon make sense?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am writing my cover letter and currently I am writing "I am also a quick learner; I was able to learn Python in two days." But it doesn't seem to be very smooth. How can this phrase be better?

Comment: Use a colon to replace the semicolon.

Comment: @deadrat How does using a colon make sense? What would it mean?

Comment: A colon separates a clause that makes a claim from one that provides a example or supporting evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Two meanings: I am also a quick learner; I was able to learn Python in two days.

to mean and, use the semi-colon

to mean consequently, use the colon

It depends on what you want to say, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps separate your points by simply saying, "I am also a quick learner.  For example, I was able to learn Python in two days."

Also since you're writing a resumé cover letter, you might want to qualify that you learned "the basics of Python" in two days rather than "everything there is to know about Python" which is what your statement seems to imply.  Just a suggestion.  Hope it helps.